# Separate function for each stored procedure or generalized function to call any procedure?

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures

In our project's current state, we have at least one method used to call each stored procedure that we have created on the database server.  Since these methods are pretty lengthy, involving creating each SqlParameter and then passing them to the database connection, I was considering creating a method that would generalize the process for our needs.

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
public static void UpdateTableTest(string procedureName, params object[] paramList)
    {
        if (sessionID == -1)
            GetActiveSession();

        SqlConnection scn = new SqlConnection(GetConnectionString());

        try
        {
            scn.Open();
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
            cmd.Connection = scn;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.CommandText = procedureName;
            SqlCommandBuilder.DeriveParameters(cmd);
            for (int i = 0; i < paramList.Length; i++)
            {
                cmd.Parameters[i+1].Value = paramList[i];
            }

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            throw ex;
        }
        finally
        {
            scn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Aside from problems that I will run in to for different query types, and for query types that I will need to return some data from, is there anything inherently wrong with this method of executing stored procedures?  Should I stick with an individual method for each stored procedure?

Comment: Get rid of that try/catch block (it just messes up your call stack), and instead put your `SqlConnection` and `SqlCommand` into `using` blocks.

Comment: The only critique I would offer here is that maintenance wise you may run into issues where order of parameters in cmd, and order of parameters of the function has to match, and it's not very explicit here.  Perhaps receive a dictionary where key is the name of parameter, and then assign by names would protect you here a bit more.  Greatest con here I think is that you're having to make a roundtrip to DB every time just to get a list of parameters - expensive.  You should know and supply parameters apriori to save the roundtrip.  It would be hard to fix it l8r if you implement this.

Comment: @LB2 I see what you're saying about the round trip.  Do you think the proper way to call each stored procedure from my C# is to have them in their own separate methods?

Comment: I think having common function is not wrong, but I would probably do the following: Expose helper method to get IDbParameter (in case you switch databases later), have callers of the function set up parameters to avoid roundtrip, then pass a list of these parameters so you can run it through this common code above).  Of course you can do it layered way allowing caller be both lazy or explicit if you want to extend this capability.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can consider using Enterprise library or

### [SQLHelpers](http://cs-dotnetnuke.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/CS_Library/Components/ApplicationBlocks/SQLHelper.cs)

available online.

example

```
DataSet dsUserInfo = new DataSet();    
dsUserInfo = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataSet("Select * from UserInfo", CommandType.Text);    
MyDataGridview.DataSource = dsUserInfo.Tables[0];
```

Or if you want to get rid of this even, you can go for ORM like EF suggested by John

Comment: Or better still, using an ORM like Entity Framework.

Comment: Thank you, this will be much more flexible for my needs.